# How can I create identical instances in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, hosting

I am new to Google Cloud Platform. Could you help me create identical instances with the same configuration that are running the same applications?

Use case scenario :
First I installed my app in GCP instance that I would like to use to create more instances with the same configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you have an existing instance that you configured and used to install your application. You’ll have to create an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#based-on-existing-instance) based on it. This template will allow you to create instances in a [managed instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups) that contain identical VMs.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but it sounds like you should look at using instance groups. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/

Comment: I want to create multiple instances for the same applcation. Obviously multiple instances are grouped together.

instance group has multiple instances:
vm-instance1
vm-instance2

I have only used the vm-instance1 when I first migrated my app to GCP.
The question is if the app needs to be installed also on every other vm-instance in the same group?

Comment: Instance groups are supposed to be identical instances. The app should be installed on all the instances, but automatically, where the instance group has a instance template, maybe referencing a custom image with your app on it, or maybe running a startup installation script, which is then used whenever a new instance is created in your instance group. If you create an instance group and add the application just to one instance, without that information ending up in the underlying template the other instances aren't ever going to know about that.